# Determine if values in a column are between 2 numbers in an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel formula that looks up if X is in between 2 values in a matrix and says yes or no (1 or 0). This formula is intended to be copied as the Y-value to the X. X column will be up to 50,000 rows and the matrix will be up to 100rows

[image]

This code works:

```
=IF(OR(AND(A2>=$D$2,A2<=$E$2),AND(A2>=$D$3,A2<=$E$3)),1,0)
```

but will get very cumbersome if the matrix gets larger, ie up to 50 rows. I also tried:

```
{=IF(AND(A2>=$D$2:$D$3,A2<=$E$2:$E$3),1,0)}
```

but returns `#VALUE!`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also make use of `SUMPRODUCT()` like so in `B2` and drag down:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A2>=$D$2:$D$3)*(A2<=$E$2:$E$3))>0,1,0)
```

[image]

And here is a way to make it easy on yourself, create a table out of your ranges, and if you add or remove from there the formula will adjust. Like so:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A2>=Tabel1[X1])*(A2<=Tabel1[X2]))>0,1,0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly the solution I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

If you can, add an extra column to the "matrix" to store the result (1,0) for each range.

Use vlookup with approximate results

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advise Ricardo. it is close to what I need, but causes other issues, I came up with something similar. The "fromX1 to X2" table will be user inputs from multiple users, and in random orders. It will be a dynamic range that will apply to the Y column. It can't be sorted as the order is required as well, so filling in the differences between the ranges automatically becomes an issue.